# Getting values back from enum sum

Tags: c#, enums, bit-manipulation, flags

I have the following enum:

```
[Flags]
public enum MyColor 
{
    None    = 0,
    Red = 1,
    Green = 2,
    Blue = 4,
    Orange = 8
}
```

I am storing the sum of allowed options in a variable say:

```
var sum = MyColor.Red | MyColor.Green | MyColor.Blue;
```

I want to extract the options back from this sum.

i.e I want to know which values are contained in this sum.I want the collection of options Red, Green and Blue from this variable back.

Can you help me doing that?

Answer (score 3):

You can try doing this

```
foreach (MyColor value in Enum.GetValues(sum.GetType()))
    if (sum.HasFlag(value))
        //Here it is, do something with it
```

Answer (score 2):

Improving on [David Pilkington](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34626762/2130976)'s answer;

```
var colorCollection = new List<MyColor>();
var colorValues = Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyColor));

foreach (var color in colorValues)
   if(sum.HasFlag(color))
      colorCollection.Add(color);
```

More on [HasFlag](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.hasflag.aspx)